# Where should I put a question about a certain phobia of my friend?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question about a certain fear of my friend, in which he prefers to sit by walls, to avert an event that has a possibility of happening. I have no idea what this phobia might be (or be called), and the friend in question feels no need to cure it.

The question, specifically, is "What might this event be?"

The friend refuses to answer my many questions about the phobia, giving me the challenge of guessing the reason he wants to sit by walls.

I have looked through all the sites, and have found nothing, so I came to Meta to decide.

Comment: Oh, and BTW, I'm only including the bare bones of what I know here. I could make the final question (if any) more detailed.

Comment: Notanearawallaphobia.  To cure, tell him the walls are made of danger.

Comment: Sentaderaportophobia? Literally "sit-back-door-fear"

Answer (score 3):

[**Cognitive Sciences**](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com) *(beta)* would seem to be your best bet. I see a number of questions in the [`phobia`](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phobia) tag asking for the name of particular kinds of phobias. Speculation on what might cause such a phobia may be too broad, so read the Help Center and some of the other questions first.

(For what it's worth, I'm from New Jersey, and I don't like to sit anywhere with my back to the entrance.)